# How to replace all values in grouped column except first row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table like this:

```
ID   Region  CreatedDate   Value
--------------------------------
1    USA     2016-01-01    5
2    USA     2016-02-02    10
3    Canada  2016-02-02    2
4    USA     2016-02-03    7
5    Canada  2016-03-03    3
6    Canada  2016-03-04    10
7    USA     2016-03-04    1
8    Cuba    2016-01-01    4
```

I need to sum column `Value` grouped by `Region` and `CreatedDate` by year and month. The result will be

```
Region  Year   Month  SumOfValue
--------------------------------
USA     2016   1       5
USA     2016   2      17
USA     2016   3       1
Canada  2016   2       2
Canada  2016   3      13
Cuba    2016   1       4
```

BUT I want to replace all repeated values in column `Region` with empty string except first met row. The finish result must be:

```
Region  Year   Month  SumOfValue
--------------------------------
USA     2016   1          5
        2016   2         17
        2016   3          1
Canada  2016   2          2
        2016   3         13
Cuba    2016   1          4
```

Thank you for a solution. It will be advantage if solution will replace also in column `Year`

Comment: Why cant do you this in application layer

Comment: It is too hard. I have to export to excel using Oracle BI Publisher - and i don't know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to get the `SumOfValue`. For the formatting, you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT
        Region,
        [Year]  = YEAR(CreatedDate),
        [Month] = MONTH(CreatedDate),
        SumOfValue = SUM(Value),
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Region ORDER BY YEAR(CreatedDate), MONTH(CreatedDate))
    FROM #tbl
    GROUP BY
        Region, YEAR(CreatedDate), MONTH(CreatedDate)
)
SELECT
    Region = CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN c.Region ELSE '' END,
    [Year],
    [Month],
    SumOfValue
FROM Cte c
ORDER BY
    c.Region, Rn
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485422)</kbd>

Although this can be done in TSQL, I suggest you do the formatting on the application side.

---

*[**Query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485422) that follows the same order as the OP.*

Comment: Excellent my dear friend! - you saved me a lot of work time)

Comment: but in SO output it have showed Cuba last but in your result set it's showing in the middle

Comment: @mohan111, this might mean that the ordering does not matter as long as data of the same country are *grouped* together.

Comment: but I'm expecting that guy of your stature will give exact output by not missing anything .. that's why I have asked out of curiosity ..I'm stern follower of your answers

Comment: @mohan111, thanks. [**Here**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485422) is the one with the correct order as per the OP.